# Resolving Zeroconf hostnames on Windows 7 between Virtualbox machines

Tags: windows, virtualbox, dns, bonjour, zeroconf

I have the following setup of VirtualBox machines on a Mac OSX host:

- several  Ubuntu servers, each running a web server and Avahi, these are set up to use "host-only" networking
- one Windows 7 box for IE testing. Here the VBox networking mode can be what ever it needs to be.

Host resolution works fine from the Mac host and between all of the Ubuntu boxes. Only the Windows 7 box can't resolve any of the ".local" names.

I tried installing the "Bonjour Printing Services" from Apple as well as the newer Bonjour version that comes with ITunes. Both didn't work.

I also tried "host-only" and "bridged" network modes for the Windows box and also switching the network connection in Windows from "Public" to "Home" or "Work".

All that didn't work and I had resort to manually editing the etc/hosts file on the Windows box which is not a viable long term solution.

Is there any solution to make this work as intended? Any firewall settings or other obscure Windows stuff?

**Update:**
Changing the name of the network adapter on the windows box from "vboxnet0" to "vboxnet1" helped. Zeroconf resolving now works. The current setup on the Windows box is:

- host-only network adapter with name "vboxnet1"
- network declared as "Work Network" in Windows' "Network and Sharing Center"
- Bonjour Printing Services (Version 2.0.2) installed

Now I'd like to know why exactly this configuration works, especially why renaming the network adapter helped.

Comment: To change the network type in Windows, this may also help: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/662e5ac6-b0c2-48e6-8a86-a00eaa9c4ba1/change-unidentified-network-networ-location-from-public-to-private